# Angular 6 mat-sidenav toggle menu not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created a sidebar nav menu in Angular 6 something like.

**UPDATE:**

But when I click on the  toggle menu icon sidebar nav should not be fullwidth expand.

But on click of toggle menu icon  in sidebar (from sidebar component), I'm not sure where the mistake is made.

**sidenav.component.html**

```html
<mat-sidenav-container fullscreen>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav  mode="side" class="example-sidenav" [ngStyle]="{ 'width.em': sidenavWidth }" opened="true" (mouseenter)="increase()"
    (mouseleave)="decrease()">
    <div class="logomain">Logo Part</div>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <mat-list-item routerLink="1" routerLinkActive="active" >
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon>person</mat-icon>
        <div fxFlex="10"></div>
        <div *ngIf="sidenavWidth > 6" class="sidenav-item">
          <h5 class="lead">About</h5>
        </div>
      </mat-list-item>

      <mat-list-item routerLink="2" routerLinkActive="active">
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon>settings</mat-icon>
        <div fxFlex="10"></div>
        <div *ngIf="sidenavWidth > 6" class="sidenav-item">
          <h5 class="lead">Services</h5>
        </div>
      </mat-list-item>

      <mat-list-item routerLink="3" routerLinkActive="active">
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon>local_phone</mat-icon>
        <div fxFlex="10"></div>
        <div *ngIf="sidenavWidth > 6" class="sidenav-item">
          <h5 class="lead">Contact</h5>
        </div>
      </mat-list-item>



    </mat-nav-list>

  </mat-sidenav>

  <div class="example-sidenav-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <mat-icon (click)="sidenav.toggle()" class="sidenav-menu">menu</mat-icon>
  </div>


</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**sidenav.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component ({
  selector: 'app-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidenav.css']
})

export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {
  sidenavWidth = 4;
  ngStyle: string;
  constructor (private router: Router) {

  }

  ngOnInit () {

  }

  increase() {
    this.sidenavWidth = 15;
    console.log('increase sidenav width');
  }
  decrease() {
    this.sidenavWidth = 4;
    console.log('decrease sidenav width');
  }
  // sidenavToggle() {
  //   this.ngStyle = 'this.sidenavWidth = 15';
  //   console.log('sidenav width incrases');
  // }
}
```

Running stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-sidenav

Comment: The problem is that the mouse cursor is directly over the sidenav after you clicked on the toggle button. When the sidenav is visible the cursor is "entering" it and that calls the `increase` method.